# Can we stop WhatsApp for one hour

Tags: whatsapp

I am receiving too much routine WhatsApp messages. It's disturbing me every secondhand and important to use while need. My question is can we stop WhatsApp for 15 minutes/30 minutes or one hour?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are dozen apps to do so. In example, I use [YourHour](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mindefy.phoneaddiction.mobilepe) and limit my manga reading app for 30 minutes a day.